# Expiry message response in push notification for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

When the device is off, I am sending push notification with expiry time to the device(IPhone).

If I have switched on the device before expiry time, I am able to receive the msg and no response from apple.

But If I have switched on the device after expiry time, Still no response from apple.

Is it possible to get the response saying "msg got expired" from apple?

Comment: just dont have an expiry, and send a timestamp of when you want it to expire in the notification, then check that time stamp in the app and decide whether that time has passed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the feedback service only indicates where you have attempted to deliver a notification to an invalid device ID. There is no indication available as to whether a notification was successfully delivered (or not) to a valid device ID.